# How to exit the program after detecting user clicked the OK button on the UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

In my program, I have a code as below. How to exit the program after **DETECTING** user click `OK` on the UIAlertView?

Thanks

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YOur Message" message:@"Your description"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: If I'm correct, Apple doesn't allow that kind of behavior. No app can terminate by other means than the home button; your app might be rejected from the App Store, if you intend to submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the cancel (your "OK") button Implement this method:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
      if(buttonIndex == 0)
          exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: It will also work nicely at getting your app rejected. Apple tell you explicitly not to do this.

Comment: @CharlesYeung: from your point of view - it works. From users point of view - it crashes. Unless you need this for private app that is not inteded for app store of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check the QA here.
see this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html)

if You want then use `exit(0);`

Comment: @Charles Yeung: don't forget to read this part: "Such usage provides a negative experience and is strongly discouraged." :)

Answer (score 0):

set AlertView delegate to self. and do your task in following delegate-

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

For capturing the ok pressed, use this:

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

   exit(0);
}
```